# How to make a program to have its own version of PATH env

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know if I can have custom version of PATH env variable specific to my executable?

Comment: Can you set the PATH env in your executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yctzx01d.aspx)() and [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkd8bxz.aspx)() to get and set PATH from within your program.

Comment: It would be good idea to store original path and restore it when your program exits.

Comment: Actually you could just use the overloaded method Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget) passing EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process as the argument to the third parameter. This will only persist the environment variable for the current process. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your executable in a script (batch file), that would to two things: (1) set the PATH; (2) invoke the original executable?

Comment: want to do it without using batch file